# Google Docs API for Android

Tags: android, google-docs

In my Android App, I wanted to list all the files in user's google docs and allow user to download file in to SD Card or Application data folder.
When I search for a tutorial or a documentation about google docs API for Android, I ended up in "google-api-java-client". I am new to Android and Java, in iOS I was able to use google docs. Can somebody suggest a good tutorial or sample code that runs in Android ?